# Retrieve file according to the language required

Tags: ios, localization

I would like to get a legal doc based on the language that the user is currently using.

The code I have is this one:

```
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *libraryDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
if (sender == privacyPolicyButton) {
        ppPath = [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"privacy_policy.html"];

    } else if (sender == termsOfServiceButton) {
        ppPath = [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"terms.html"];

    } else if (sender == endUserButton) {
        ppPath = [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"eula.html"];

    }

    NSData *ppData = nil;
    policyView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    [loadingIndicator startAnimating];
    policyView.hidden = closePolicyButton.hidden = NO;
    privacyPolicyButton.hidden = termsOfServiceButton.hidden = endUserButton.hidden = YES;

    ppData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:ppPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", ppPath);

    [policyView loadData:ppData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

I have a version of each document in spanish and in english, how can I tell the path to use the version in spanish?

[image: This is how the files look]

Comment: If the files are in the app's resource bundle, get the path using `[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]`. It will give you the right version automatically.

Comment: Actually you are right!! [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"privacy_policy" ofType:@"html"] gives me the right version :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please put an official answer so I can mark it as correct? ;)

Comment: I posted the answer as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSBundle` class does this for you. Assuming your HTML files are part of the app's resource bundle, you can simply do:

```
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"terms" ofType:@"html"];
```

This will give you the path to the proper terms.html file based on the user's locale/language setting.